# Word for "done slowly because of bad mood/lack of energy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Example:

> [...] he pulled out his phone and cancelled
>   his flight to Hawaii.

The only word I can think of is *languishly*. But I think it's not used very often in that [way](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22Languishly%2C%20he%22&oq=%22Languishly%2C%20he%22&gs_l=serp.12...0.0.0.151381.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.serp..0.0.0.dst_pIeFr5Q).

Comment: Many (not all) of the suggested adverbs would be better placed after the verb phrase *pull out his phone* in my opinion. Is knowing where to place the adverb a problem for you?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Well, not much. You think that *lethargically* cancelling a flight doesn't make much sense?

Comment: Now, you're changing things round. I never said it didn't make sense, I suggested that not all the adverbs should go at the beginning of the sentence. Your phrase above is completely different from the original. Your original example also has the expression *pulled out his phone and*. You can of course delete that phrase and still have a grammatical sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing something slowly because of a bad mood could be **reluctantly**.

> [reluctantly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reluctantly) (adv) - in an unwilling and hesitant way

If it's because of a lack of energy, it could be **lethargically**.

> [lethargic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/lethargic) (adj) - sluggish and apathetic

Answer (score 1):

[Languid](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/languid?s=t)

> Lacking in vigor or vitality; slack or slow:

[Lethargic](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lethargic?s=ts)

> Of, relating to, or affected with lethargy; drowsy; sluggish; apathetic.

Answer (score 1):

- **lackadaisically**

The adjective form is *lackadaisical*.

> lackadaisical 
>   [lak-uh-dey-zi-kuh l]
>   adjective
>   1. without interest, vigor, or determination; listless; lethargic: a lackadaisical attempt.
>   2. lazy; indolent: a lackadaisical fellow.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lackadaisical

Answer (score 1):

One more: **indolently**.

- "indolent" definition: lazy or disinterested in acting.

Also **sluggishly**.

- "sluggish" definition: lacking alertness, vigor, or energy; inert or averse to activity or exertion.

Answer (score 0):

"lethargically"

[lethargic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lethargic): (adj.) feeling a lack of energy or a lack of interest in doing things